# Camera App crash prior to onActivityResult - either no error or result is -1 and data is null

Tags: java, android, android-camera-intent

I'm doing a very small app that should start the builtin camera app on the push of a button. When a picture has been taken I'd like to return to the app and display the picture.

The code bellow works well up until the onActivityResult method. The image file is indeed created, and the picture is saved to it. But for some reason, prior to running onActiveResult one of two different errors occurs (can't find a pattern as to what error appears).

Sometimes the app just stops and there is no error in logcat. Other times I get a exception: `Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=100, result=-1, data=null}`

It appears that the return result code is -1 (should be 100) - what does this mean? Also, the return data itself is null. Why?

Here's the code (I've been following Androids [camera app guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html))

```
package se.danielsetreus.dansetcamera1;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.io.File;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;
private static final int CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 100;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Log.d("DansetCamera1", "Start the app!");
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // Tried adding this - but it did not help
    //super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Log.d("Danset", "RequestCode is " + requestCode);
    Log.d("Danset", "ResultCode is " + resultCode + " Needed to be " + RESULT_OK);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        Log.d("danset", "Image saved to \n" + data.getData());
    else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED)
        Log.d("danset", "You canceled");
    else
        Log.d("danset", "Image capture failed");
}

// Create a file Uri for saving an image or video
private static Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type){
    Uri i =  Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));
    Log.d("Danset", "Created file " + i.toString());
    return i;
}

// Create a File for saving an image or video
private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type){
    File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "DansetCamera1");

    // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
    if (! mediaStorageDir.exists()){
        if (! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
            Log.d("MyCameraApp", "failed to create directory");
            return null;
        }
    }

    // Create a media file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    File mediaFile;
    if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE){ // Prepares for also handling video
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
                "IMG_"+ timeStamp + ".jpg");
    } else {
        return null;
    }

    return mediaFile;
}

private void startCamera(Uri uri) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);
    startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
}

public void snapPic(View view) {
    Uri pictureFile = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
    Log.d("Danset", "Created file!");
    startCamera(pictureFile);
}
}
```

A thousand thanks for any help!

Comment: did u try adding super.onactivityresult() on the first line of your activityResult method? bcoz I see u r missing that..

Comment: I tried it but no change though. App crashed when trying to return from the camera app. Added `super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);` in the first line of onActivityResult

Comment: probably u shud try to use logcats instead of toast msg.. I suspect them in ur case.. Atleast for the RESULT_OK case

Comment: Updated my original question - replacing the toasts with log prints. Does not help. Still the app crash on return.

Comment: Pls post your logcat.

Comment: I would if I could - but my logcat's not printing anything after the launch of the camera app. The app just closes down with a "Sorry" message in the phone.

Comment: So I manage to get it working by moving the launch of the camera intent to a different activity than my main (launcher) activity. That made the return to my app work, it seems. Also - the return data parameter is null, and from what I can find that's just a stupid fact. So I stored the fileUri in a instance variable prior to launching the camera intent. But perhaps someone can enlighten me as to why it's not possible to launch the camera intent from the launcher activity?